# Matplotlib showing wrong y-axis values

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

My code is very simple:

```
values = [-2071238, -2071241, -2071240, -2071242, -2071244, -2071239, -2071221, -2071194, -2071224, -2071240, -2071244, -2071241, -2071240, -2071241, -2071237, -2071223, -2071205, -2071225, -2071238]
indx = [0.0, 20.0, 40.0, 60.0, 80.0, 100.0, 120.0, 140.0, 160.0, 180.0, 200.0, 220.0, 240.0, 260.0, 280.0, 300.0, 320.0, 340.0, 360.0]

plt.scatter(indx, values)

#rendering
plt.xlabel("Axis 1")
plt.ylabel("Axis 2")
title = "All"
plt.title(title)
plt.savefig(title + ".png")
plt.show()
```

However, the resulting figure is the following:

[image: picture]

Which obviously doesn't have the good y values for each points.

Am I doing something wrong or forgetting something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your figure does have good values on the y axis, but they have an offset. The offset can be disabled:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

values = [-2071238, -2071241, -2071240, -2071242, -2071244, -2071239, -2071221, -2071194, -2071224, -2071240, -2071244, -2071241, -2071240, -2071241, -2071237, -2071223, -2071205, -2071225, -2071238]
indx = [0.0, 20.0, 40.0, 60.0, 80.0, 100.0, 120.0, 140.0, 160.0, 180.0, 200.0, 220.0, 240.0, 260.0, 280.0, 300.0, 320.0, 340.0, 360.0]

plt.scatter(indx, values)

# disabling the offset on y axis
ax = plt.gca()
ax.ticklabel_format(useOffset=False)

#rendering
plt.xlabel("Axis 1")
plt.ylabel("Axis 2")
title = "All"
plt.title(title)
plt.savefig(title + ".png")

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I don't understand how the offset can be right. It is most of the time multiplied by negative values, so I think the result should be positive?

Comment: @Antys - offset means that 0 tick on your graph is shifted and equal to -2071200 (which is the same as -2.0712e6). When values assigned to the ticks on y axis are added to the offset they give the same values as on the graph which I added (e.g. -2071200 + (-10) = -2071210). Your problem is that you're trying to multiply offset by values assigned to the ticks instead of adding them.

Comment: An important addition: If one of your axes is a date, the above call to `ax.ticklabel_format(useOffset=False)` will FAIL. In that case you will need to explicitly specify the axis that is _not_ the date axis via `ax.ticklabel_format(axis="y", useOffset=False)` (here, x is the date axis). Reason being that the axis parameter is set to "both" by default, and `ax.ticklabel_format` will throw a "This method only works with the ScalarFormatter" otherwise.